# handle different PHP validation response into Ajax to display in alert bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form for password recovery via email. I send input to PHP to do the following:

1. Validate {three different validation messages)
2. If passed, Process

Once the response is received, in AJAX, although is not valid, it is considered successful because it has been processed in `php`.

I need to differentiate between every response so I can display appropriate alert messages

- if field input is empty, I want to show it in `alert-info` message box
- if field input is noa t valid email, I want to show it in `alert-warning` message box
- if field input is not found the in server, I want to show it in `alert-danger` message box
- if successful, I want to show it in alert-success

```js
$(function() {
 // Get FORM ID ///////////////////////////////////////////
 var form = $('#RecoveryForm');
 // Get MESSAGE DIV ID ///////////////////////////////////////////
 var formMessages = $('#formresults');
 $(form).submit(function(e) {
  $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", false ); 
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(form).serialize();
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
   })
  .done(function(response) {
   $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
   $(formMessages).addClass('success');
   $(formMessages).text(response);
   // Get FORM ID ///////////////////////////////////////////
   document.getElementById("RecoveryForm").reset();
   //$('#reset-button').click();
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
   $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
   $(formMessages).addClass('error');

   if (data.responseText !== '') {
    $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
   } else {
    $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
   }
  });
 $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");  
 });
});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="formresults"></div>  
 <form id="RecoveryForm" method="post" action="exa.php">
      <table align="center">
      <tr><td><div class="input-append"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" /><span class="add-on"><li class="icon-envelope"></li></span></div></td></tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=Token::generate();?>" />
      <center><input type="submit" id="submit" name="Forget" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" /></center>
    </form>
   <script src="ajax/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="ajax/app.js"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code >>

```
<?php   
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'Access.php'; // Get Access
//response array with status code and message
$response_array = array();    
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    $email = $_POST["email"];                   

    if ( empty($email) ) {                      
        $response_array['status'] = 'info';
        $response_array['message'] = 'No Input';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit;   
        }
    if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $response_array['status'] = 'warning';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Not Valid Email';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit;   
        }
    if (@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `accounts` WHERE `email`='$email'")) < 1) {
        $response_array['status'] = 'danger';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Account Not Found';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        exit;   
        }
            $row_user = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `email`='$email'"));
            $password = $row_user['pass'];
            $to = $row_user['email'];
            $subject = "Your Recovered Password";
            $message = "Please use this password to login: " . $password;
            $headers = "From : XXX@hotmail.com";
    // Send the email.
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        $response_array['status'] = 'Success';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Email Sent';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        } else {
        $response_array['status'] = 'info';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Try Again Later';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
                }
} else {
$response_array['status'] = 'info';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Try Again Later';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
}
$response_array['status'] = 'info';
        $response_array['message'] = 'Try Again Later';
        echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```

Comment: did my answer fail to solve your problem?

Comment: @BobbyAxe it did but I need the validation on PHP because I have the codes already built in there. I found another way check it out if you are iinterested.

Comment: @BobbyAxe Many thx for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we start validation from the html of cause this can be hampered and manipulated by the user but still a good way to start.

first we add the `required` attribute to your input fields in html and change the `input types` to match the data types your expecting eg: `input type="email"` hiding an input does not prevent it form being tampered with, best to add the `Readonly` attribute also.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="formresults"></div>     
        <form id="RecoveryForm" method="post" action="exa.php">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <input type="email" Required name="email" id="email" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" />
                            <span class="add-on"><li class="icon-envelope"></li></span>
                            <p id="mailerror"></p> <!-- This Segment Displays The Validation Rule For Email -->
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" Readonly name="token" value="<?=Token::generate();?>" />
            <center>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Forget" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </center>
            <script src="ajax/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="ajax/app.js"></script>
        </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Second of all you are using jquery although this much much more easy to use i will suggest you start with java script validation, using the `onsubmit` attribute to catch the form and begin validation. you will be better understand what exactly is going on as a beginner rather than jquery.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    /*Get FORM ID*/
    var form = $('#RecoveryForm');

    /*Get MESSAGE DIV ID */
    var formMessages = $('#formresults');

    /*Email Validation*/
    var email_regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    var email = $('#email').val();

    if (!email.match(email_regex) || email.length == 0) {
    $('#mailerror').text("* Please enter a valid email address *");
    $("#email").focus();
    return false;
    }
    else if (email.match(email_regex) && email.length >= 5){
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        $( "#submit" ).prop( "disabled", false ); 
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
            })
        .done(function(response) {
            if (response.status=='Success'){
                $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                $(formMessages).addClass('success');
                $(formMessages).text(response.message);
            }
            else if (response.status=='warning'){
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');
                $(formMessages).text(response.message);
            }
            else if (response.status=='danger'){
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');
                $(formMessages).text(response.message);
            }
            else if (response.status=='info'){
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');
                $(formMessages).text(response.message);
            }

            /*Get FORM ID */
            document.getElementById("RecoveryForm").reset();
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });
    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");        
    });
    }
 });
</script>
```

Third of all your PHP could have been better written but it works fine presumably :( so we leave that for now.

Comment: please feel free to edit my answer and make it more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

report different response with php validation

```js
.done(function(response) {
   var messageAlert = response.type;
   var messageText = response.message;
   var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + '"style="margin-top:10px;"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><d style="font-size:11px; ">' + messageText + '</d></div>';
   (formMessages).html(alertBox);
```

For every PHP statement add:

```
$responseArray = array('type' => 'alert-warning', 'message' => '<b>Alert!</b>There is not enough credit');
```

Then send response json encoded

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);     header('Content-Type: application/json');   echo $encoded; } else {    echo $responseArray['message'];      }
```